# Typescript extract from mapped type, the specific value of the union type of the props

Tags: typescript, union-types, mapped-types

My goal would be to get the output variable with correctly typed properties using ValueType as a "translator". My problem is that I can't pass as a ValueType parameter the specific value of the unionType, but only the unionType itself. As a result I get that all properties can take all possible values provided by ValueType.

```
enum Kind {
    AsIs = 'AsIs',
    Fields = 'Fields',
    Category = 'Category'
};

interface Type {
    field: string;
    category: number;
    color: string;
}

type KindSetting<T> = { [k in keyof T]: Kind };

const a: KindSetting<Type> = {
    field: Kind.Fields,
    category: Kind.Category,
    color: Kind.AsIs,
};

type ValueType<T extends Kind> =
    T extends Kind.Fields ? boolean :
    T extends Kind.AsIs ? string :
    T extends Kind.Category ? number :
    never;

type Output<T> = { [K in keyof T]: ValueType<KindSetting<T>[K]> }

const output: Output<Type> = {
    field: '',
    category: 5,
    color: ''
};
```

here the code on the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBA0gliAJlA3gKCpqBBAzgSVygF4oByPQsgGgywDE5gAbRI0sxltmuzAYQCGAF2ABzAPYAnAJ4lyQ0ZNlk0AXwDcaNAlFSAZoIDGwKABUZAB1PosUfU1YAuKLmFSEYrXaMjx0mRdwCAAjYClvLCMJZmkXNw8QL3VtYStTeCQAZWBhYU8AHjMAPnkUKABtAGsoBCgq4BkJfXMAXRdM5E1taJA3KEEOhEQcvMKLa1LSWywHbiGkADouVlxaHz9lQNhhxcV-WXWomLidpco19S00NOsoADVBZjBgCeAiqGAAD1EkIk6pnxzJ8fqA2GdEMtHOCAPxQEISGLAQQgKBOIFmEG-cGdRYXKBwhKeNEYrFg-67fZbAlQYJhKQkuwgYAAN3C11upgA8mBhJZeUUpqhKjBaqiGk0WmZ2g8ni83gVOqN8klBRUYK1SmoehI%20sJ4S4eXyBW8hTNMHNnOReBslAEXABWI6YaKxKQuMiqbpAA)

Comment: Can you add an example of what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand, you are enforcing the `output` to be of the type of `a` variable, i.e. `{ field: boolean; category: number; color: string }`.

You have to declare `a` to be of its literal type: `{ field: Kind.Fields }`, not the general `{ field: Kind }`, to be used with the `output`; otherwise, the general `Kind` type will yield `boolean | string | number` type. The `Output` type would also have to be changed a little bit.

By the way, I'd like to present an alternative to your `ValueType` type.

```js
const a = {
  field: Kind.Fields,
  category: Kind.Category,
  color: Kind.AsIs,
} as const;

type ValueType<T extends Kind> =
  T extends Kind.Fields ? boolean :
  T extends Kind.AsIs ? string :
  T extends Kind.Category ? number :
  never;

interface KindMapping {
  [Kind.Fields]: boolean;
  [Kind.AsIs]: string;
  [Kind.Category]: number;
}

type Output<T extends KindSetting<T>> = { [K in keyof T]: KindMapping[T[K]] };
// ValueType<T[K]> can also be used instead of KindMapping[T[K]]

const output: Output<typeof a> = {
  field: '', // error, must be boolean
  category: 5,
  color: ''
};
```

If you don't use `a` variable elsewhere, you can make it an interface/type instead of a concrete variable.

```
interface A {
  field: Kind.Fields;
  category: Kind.Category;
  color: Kind.AsIs;
}

const output: Output<A> = { // same effect
  field: '',
  category: 5,
  color: '',
};
```